# Could you please find the Laplace transform?

Tags: control-system, laplace-transform

I can use the table directly, but I am struggling how to make the combination. This equation will help me to work on my gyroscope sensor equations ( magnetic based ) , My pain point is at the combination.

$$ t^n\mathrm{e}^{-at}\sin\omega t $$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework question with no attempt shown.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question? [What is the Laplace transform for this equation?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519647/what-is-the-laplace-transform-for-this-equation). Edit and add details there.

Comment: A magnetic based gyroscope sensor? Can you provide a part # for that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Find Laplace transform of  sinωt i.e X(s)

2 .replace s by (s+a) in Laplace transform of sinωt ,you got X(s+a)

3.differentiate X(s+a)   by  n  times with respect to s and that's you answer

Method for n times differentiation-
1.partial fraction X(s+a) ,here poles will be of complex form
2.and then differentiate both partial fractions by n times and after that combine then , hopefully you'll get your answer

Comment: I'll add how you should differentiate n times ,I think you make some mistake there

Answer (score 0):

The results using Mathematica.

```
LaplaceTransform[t^n Exp[-a t] Sin[w t], t, s]
```

> $$\Gamma (n+1) \left((a+s)^2+w^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2} (-n-1)} \sin \left((n+1) \tan
>    ^{-1}\left(\frac{w}{a+s}\right)\right)$$

It simplifies to rational functions with numeric values

```
With[{n = 2, a = 1, w = 3}, LaplaceTransform[t^n Exp[-a t] Sin[w t], t, s]]
```

> $$\frac{18 \left(s^2+2 s-2\right)}{\left(s^2+2 s+10\right)^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

I used wxmaxima to calculate the problem, and that is the result:

[image]